# Postgrest permission denied certain tables

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

We're using Postgrest api for web.
Literally certain tables get permission denied from api call..
Looks like this is about table policy but there is nothing new about this table's policy.

here's error message
[when call api's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji0vT.png)

I have no idea where can I start digging...

Can get json result from api calls

Comment: Zero information, so no answer is possible.

Comment: Start by... checking what the ownership and grants on the table are? By trying to reproduce the problem with psql?

Comment: Who creates table `orders`? What permissions are on the table? What user do you use to authenticate? What groups (roles) does it belong to? Does it inherit the rights of the roles it is a member  of?
Also - there is no need to include a link to a picture with a plain text information inside. You could have copy/pasted the error message as a text. Some people might be unwilling to click on random links and you reduce the possibility of getting help.

Comment: Try using SQL or a tool like pgadmin to check to permissions assigned to the ‘orders’ table, also ensure that the user make the api calls has the necessary permissions on the ‘orders’ table `SELECT table_name, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE table_name = 'orders';`

Comment: As the comments mention, more information is needed. What's the exact request that you're doing? Are you using JWT? If you are, then check the `role` inside that JWT and `GRANT SELECT ON <table> TO <role>;` to allow access to it. If not, and you're using only anonymous requests, then check in your PostgREST `config` file, who is the `db-anon-role` and `GRANT SELECT ON <table> TO <anon-role>;`. If you need info on how PostgREST works, [check the tutorials](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/tutorials/tut0.html) for a simple example.